# How to configure Angular proxy on the Server prod?

Tags: node.js, angular, proxy, http-redirect, dev-to-production

I am testing a new aproach in my front end App build with Angular, and i want to hide the API url from the browser Network. form example : to call login on api.url.dz/login i want to call front.url.dz/login on the front then redirecte this to api.url.dz/login .
here is my proxy.config.json file :

```
{
    "http://localhost:4200":{
        "target":"http://localhost:9999/",
        "secure":false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel":"debug",
        "pathRewrite": {"^/authenticate": "authenticate",
                        "^/authenticate-refresh": "authenticate-refresh",
                        "^/refresh-token": "refresh-token",
                        "^/auth-logout": "auth-logout"
                    }
                    }
}
```

this works on localhost because i start project with this command :

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

but in production server when executing :

```
ng build
```

it doesn't work 
this is the config in prod server :

```
{
    "https://front.domaine.dz":{
        "target":"https://back.domaine.dz:9999",
        "secure":false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel":"debug",
        "pathRewrite": {"^/authenticate": "authenticate",
                        "^/authenticate-refresh": "authenticate-refresh",
                        "^/refresh-token": "refresh-token",
                        "^/auth-logout": "auth-logout"
                    }
                    }
}
```

i want to know if there is an alternative to execute with proxy option in ng build command ?

angular.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "argon-dashboard-angular": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/scss/argon.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
              "node_modules/clipboard/dist/clipboard.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "argon-dashboard-angular-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "argon-dashboard-angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "argon-dashboard-angular",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Please also share your `angular.json` file. Besides, I don't think you need the full domain as key in your proxy.conf.json, but rather the actual endpoint. So instead of `https://example.com/api` you just type `/api`. Then all calls to `/api` will be proxied.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner but in the proxy-config.json file it can't be conidered on the production server because i build with jenkins with ng build command .

Answer (score 0):

Angular proxy is not meant to be used in production.

You can circumvent this by running `ng serve` with your proxy configuration in production but that's bad practice.

You have to configure your web server (apache/nginx/other) to proxy requests according to your `proxy.config.json` (as in, use the relevant directives to get the same behavior as your `proxy.config.json`).

For instance, you can use `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` with Apache.

Comment: thank you , that's what i am doing i am configuring the nginx to redirect to the api urls , but i want if any one can help to do it like i want in the proxy-config.json with ng build .
hope we will find an other approach in the answers. thank you an other time !